# Export interface in typescript results in not exported when building in second project

Tags: typescript

I'm a bit confused why exporting an interface in typescript is not working:

```
import { IView } from "./IView";

interface IModule {
  id: string;
  route: string;
  routeName: string;
  view: IView;
  title: string;
  component: string;
  modules: IModule[];
}

export { IModule };
```

IView works okay, and that's exported and imported identically, is it that IModule references itself?

When building I get the following error:

```
"export 'IModule' was not found in './controls/interfaces/IModule'
```

When importing it (npm i) and then building I get the following error:

```
"IModule" is not exported by "node_modules/.../controls/interfaces/IModule.ts", imported by "node_modules/.../src/main.js".
```

Sorry, I'm still learning typescript, I was a C# dev and never had an issue like this.

Changing the interface to:

```
import { IView } from "./IView";

type IModule = {
  id: string;
  route: string;
  routeName: string;
  view: IView;
  title: string;
  component: string;
  //modules: any;//IModule[];
} & { modules: IModule };

export { IModule };
```

removes the first error but importing and building in the other project results in the same error:

```
"IModule" is not exported by "node_modules/.../controls/interfaces/IModule.ts", imported by "node_modules/.../src/main.js".
```

Comment: Try with `export interface IModule {   }`. React does support recursive interfaces.